# Are curried event handlers less performant than normal function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have an event handler that is curried, and pass the outer function to an onClick handler, that outer function runs and saves that parameter to the closure. So if I do this on 10 items, when the component mounts, this function will run ten times.

Here is an example:

```
const handleNavigationClick = (index: number) => () => {
    setActivePillIndex(index);
  };

onClick={handleNavigationClick(index)}
```

My question is this: Is this approach less performant than the traditional way like:

```
const handleNavigationClick = (index: number) => {
    setActivePillIndex(index);
  };

onClick={() => handleNavigationClick(index)}
```

Comment: ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Comment: You are premature optimazing without a reason, do you have a bottleneck? Do you have a lot of complaining users? Did you measure anything and came to a conclusion? Even if we give you an answer it might no satisfy you since you can optimize the rendering time even more.

Comment: And they perform the same, both of them will cause the child component to rerender, thus if we decide that we measure "performance" by if its makes unnecessary renders .